# Jupyter ipywidget: use one slider widget in one specifc tab in notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, ipywidgets

I am trying to create ipywidgets tab and I am looking for one particular numeric widget in a tab, currently, I am seeing both the tabs as common, how can I see size1 in tab[out2] specifically. My existing code looks like following

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import HBox, VBox, Button, Layout, Label
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual

size = widgets.IntSlider(value=50, min=0,max=100,step=1, description='size:')
size1 = widgets.IntSlider(value=20, min=0,max=50,step=1, description='size1:')

def hist1(size):
    data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size = size))
    data.plot.hist()
    return

def hist2(size1):
    data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size = size1))
    data.plot.box()
    return

ui = widgets.VBox([size,size1])

out1 = widgets.interactive_output(hist1, {'size':size})
out2 = widgets.interactive_output(hist2, {'size1':size1})

tab  = widgets.Tab(children = [out1, out2])
tab.set_title(0, 'hist')
tab.set_title(1, 'box')

display(ui,tab)
```

it's giving me following

[image]

but I am seeking to see size1 slider in out2 i.e. box tab, how can I do this with existing code to have a specific slider for tabs

Answer (score 1):

The `Interact` classes are similarly named but have different functions. `widgets.interactive` will create a VBox of your input and output widgets, but not display them to screen. You can then pass them as children to your `Tab` call. No need to display the UI separately.

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import HBox, VBox, Button, Layout, Label
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual

size = widgets.IntSlider(value=50, min=0,max=100,step=1, description='size:')
size1 = widgets.IntSlider(value=20, min=0,max=50,step=1, description='size1:')

def hist1(size):
    data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size = size))
    data.plot.hist()
    return

def hist2(size1):
    data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size = size1))
    data.plot.box()
    return

out1 = widgets.interactive(hist1, size=size)
out2 = widgets.interactive(hist2, size1=size1)

tab  = widgets.Tab(children = [out1, out2])
tab.set_title(0, 'hist')
tab.set_title(1, 'box')

display(tab)
```